# iOS pointer using gyro

Tags: ios, iphone, gyroscope

I'm trying to build a pointer using the gyro in an iPhone. Right now I send gyro-data to a windows application from an iPhone over TCP but I want it to send two dimensional data that the app can use more directly to control a pointer. To start sending data a button is pressed. The orientation the phone is in when the button is pressed should be "the starting point", and how the phone is tilted from that is what should be sent.

So say I have the phone in my hand while lying down, I press the button (0, 0) and tilt it forward so that the top of the phone moves closer and closer  pointing toward the ceiling (0.54, 0).

Is there any library I can use to transform the gyro data to a two dimensional representation or will I have to dust off my algebra? Are there any good resources for doing it algebraically?